# \textbf and other \text command don't work

Tags: fonts, formatting

i have a document ike this:

```
\documentclass[12pt,openany]{book}      % paper size is in preamble.sty

\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}

%%%%%%%%% GRAPHICS %%%%%%%%%%%%%%
\usepackage{graphicx}
\graphicspath{{images/}}

\usepackage{csquotes}

%%%%%%%%%% BOOK INFORMATION %%%%%%%%%%
\newcommand{\authorname}{AUTHOR}
\newcommand{\booktitle}{TITILE}
\newcommand{\subtitle}{SUBTITILE}
\newcommand{\publisher}{PUBLISHER}
\newcommand{\editionyear}{2021}
\title{\booktitle}
\author{\authorname}

\usepackage{misc/options}

\begin{document}
\frontmatter
\input{frontmatter/titlepage}
\input{frontmatter/preface}
\input{frontmatter/tocpage}

\mainmatter
\pagestyle{fancy}

\input{content/chapter1}

\end{document}
```

My options like here:

```
\usepackage[activate={true,nocompatibility},final,tracking=true,kerning=true,spacing=true,factor=1100,stretch=10,shrink=10, babel=true]{microtype}   % Better typography

\usepackage{lettrine}   % Add drop caps to chapter openings
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

\newcommand{\hsp}{\kern 1pt}    % for nested quotation marks

% Paragraph formatting
\renewcommand{\baselinestretch}{1.125}      % Allow paragraphs to breathe by spreading the lines further
\setlength{\parskip}{0pt}                   % Fixed space between paragraphs (i.e. disable variable parskip)
\setlength{\parindent}{1em}

% Don’t add extra space after sentences
\frenchspacing

% Reduce widows/orphans
\widowpenalty=10000
\clubpenalty=10000

% Page size
\usepackage[
    paperheight=9in,
    paperwidth=6in,
    top=0.75in,
    bottom=0.75in,
    outer=0.75in,
    inner=0.875in
]{geometry}

% Reduce overfull \hbox{} warnings
\sloppy

% Contents page
\usepackage[titles]{tocloft}
\renewcommand{\cftchapfont}{\large\itshape}
\renewcommand{\cftchappagefont}{\normalfont}
\renewcommand{\numberline}[1]{}

% chapter headings
\renewcommand\thechapter{\Roman{chapter}}
\usepackage[center,sc]{titlesec}

% headers/footers
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\setlength{\headheight}{15pt}
\pagestyle{fancy}
\fancyhf{}
\renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0pt}
\fancyhf[CFE,CFO]{\thepage}         % Set page numbers in the footer
%\fancyhead[LE,RO]{\thepage}        % Set page numbers in the left/right sides of the header
%\fancyhead[CE]{\itshape\authorname} % Author name in middle of left-side page header
%\fancyhead[CO]{\itshape\booktitle}  % Book title in middle of right-side page header
```

But when I try to make my text (in some chapters) bold using **\textbf{my text}** command I don't see anything change. Any idea what's going on ? Maybe it's because I use Russian in addition to English?

[image: textbf]
Here is example textbf doesnt work

Also i have a little message

Comment: Are you loading `amsmath`?

Comment: @egreg No, I don't need mathematical formulas. I just added the command to add this package and nothing has changed.

Comment: Can you please add some paragraphs that illustrate what doesn't work?

Comment: @egreg added new info

Comment: @egreg I rather think that `ebgaramond` is the problem. I'm not sure cyrillic glyphs work with pdftex.

Comment: @campa I just commented out this package and everything worked! thank you!

Comment: @campa Please make your suggestion as answer...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your problem can be reproduced by the shorter code

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[T1,T2A]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,russian]{babel}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}
\begin{document}
Chapter, Глава, \textbf{Chapter}, \textbf{Глава}
\end{document}
```

which results in
[image]

The trouble is that `ebgaramond` with `pdftex` does not support the T2A encoding. In fact, the console shows the warnings

```
LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T2A/EBGaramond-OsF/m/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T2A/cmr/m/n' instead on input line 6.

LaTeX Font Warning: Font shape `T2A/EBGaramond-OsF/bx/n' undefined
(Font)              using `T2A/EBGaramond-OsF/m/n' instead on input line 7.
```

Following the expansion of `\begin{document}` on line 6, TeX finds the macro `\normalsize` and tries to set up the font, which after loading `ebgaramond` should be `T2A/EBGaramond-OsF/m/n`. However, this font does not exists: the solution to this conundrum is provided by the file `t2aenc.def`, which contains (more or less) the line

```
\DeclareFontSubstitution{T2A}{cmr}{m}{n}
```

which means "*if you are using the T2A encoding and you don't find the declared font, then fall back to `cmr` instead*". LaTeX then switches to the font `T2A/cmr/m/n`, and warns you about it.

Then, on line 7 `\textbf` triggers boldface, and LaTeX looks for `T2A/EBGaramond-OsF/bx/n`. However, also this does not exists, and as replacement TeX uses the normal (non-bold) font, but that has been *also* replaced before! The result is that you don't get anything bold.

You could remove the `fontenc` and `inputenc` lines and use a Unicode-aware engine like `luatex`. However, Garamond doesn't have boldface anyway, so unless you want to start setting up different fonts for English/Russian, the easiest solution is to remove `ebgaramond`.